# Open() in Python not working on my pc

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to use `open()` to open a file, but I got the error below:

```
open("C:\Users\stu\Documents\Python\projects\lab\docs\test.txt","r")
```

> file "C:\Users\stu\Documents\Python\projects\lab\docs")
>   no such file or directory
>   C:\Users\stu\Documents\Python\projects\lab\docs\test.txt

I did that in other pc and worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use a raw string. like `r"C:\..."`. Now the backslash is interpreted as escaping char. That's one of the many things why I like linux: it uses slashes `/`.

Comment: Backslashes have special meaning in string literals. Use forward slashes, or escape the backslashes, or use a raw string literal `r'...'` instead of `'...'` (although raw strings can't end in a single backslash).

Comment: Here, `\t` at the beginning of `\test` gets interpreted as a `TAB`

Comment: done, i did not realize in this pc windows was hiding the extentions, i use to save the files by its extentions, so the file name was actually test.txt.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is a special character in Python. Try using a raw string by prepending an `r`:

```
r"C:\Users\stu\Documents\Python\projects\lab\docs\test.txt"
```

Comment: not working, this is the first time that this happent

Comment: Are you sure the file exists in this place?